# $\limsup_n a_n+b_n+c_n+\limsup_n b_n \le \limsup_n a_n+b_n+\limsup_n b_n+c_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1},(b_n)_{n\ge 1},(c_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be sequences of reals in $[0,1]$. Is it true that
$$
\limsup_n (a_n+b_n+c_n)+\limsup_n b_n \le \limsup_n (a_n+b_n)+\limsup_n (b_n+c_n)?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is in general not valid.

A counter example: For $n\in\mathbb N$ let
\begin{align}
  a_n &=  \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}, &
  b_n &= \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{2}, &
  c_n &= a_n.
\end{align}
Then, we have
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n + c_n) + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n = 1 + \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 $$
and
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) + \limsup_{n\to\infty} (b_n + c_n) = 1 + 1 = 2. $$